# Oracle SQL using group by: Can you group by a field used to join two tables?

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, outer-join

```
SELECT b.first_name, b.last_name, SUM(t.price_total)
FROM brokers b
LEFT OUTER JOIN
trades t
ON b.broker_id=t.broker_id
GROUP BY
b.broker_id
```

My problem question asks to 'Display the total value of each broker's trades'. The answer groups by `b.first_name||' '||b.last_name`, but I think the group by should be done via the broker's ID (i.e. two people with the same name could be grouped together, this wouldn't happen via broker id).

yet when running my code, i get an error

```
ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 1 Column: 8
```

my question is, why can't I use b.broker_id as the only column to group by?

Comment: The general GROUP BY rule says:
If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT b.broker_id, b.first_name, b.last_name, SUM(t.price_total)
FROM brokers b
LEFT OUTER JOIN
trades t
ON b.broker_id=t.broker_id
GROUP BY
b.broker_id, b.first_name, b.last_name
```

When you use GROUP BY, select clause can have only the columns specified in GROUP BY and aggregated/calculated fields for that group like sum, average, min, max etc.

You can use analytic functions to overcome it, this is mainly used to avoid self joins and get the all the fields you require while doing aggregations:

```
SELECT distinct * from (SELECT b.first_name, b.last_name, 
SUM(t.price_total) over (partition by b.broker_id) price_total
FROM brokers b
LEFT OUTER JOIN
trades t
ON b.broker_id=t.broker_id);
```

Comment: While that does work (thanks), why can't I use only the broker id column?
My understanding is you can group by any column that is non-aggregated, and you can group by columns not in the SELECT. broker id fulfils both requirements

Answer (score 2):

A slightly different approach is to group the trades by broker ID, then join the result of that to the brokers table:

```
SELECT b.first_name, b.last_name, price_sum
FROM brokers b
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
  SELECT broker_id,  SUM(price_total) AS price_sum
  FROM trades
  GROUP BY broker_id
) t
ON b.broker_id=t.broker_id
```

Personally I feel like this expresses more clearly what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Just add last_name and first_name in GROUP BY

```
SELECT b.first_name, b.last_name, SUM(t.price_total)
FROM brokers b
LEFT OUTER JOIN
trades t
ON b.broker_id=t.broker_id
GROUP BY
b.broker_id,b.first_name, b.last_name
```

If two people have the same last and first names, it will be different rows in the result because of broker_id in GROUP BY

Comment: Thanks, but same question as the user above, why can't I use ONLY the broker id column?
My understanding is you can group by any column that is non-aggregated, and you can group by columns not in the SELECT. broker id fulfils both requirements

Comment: @shen ALL columns in the SELECT statement, which is not in aggregate function, MUST be in GROUP BY. The problem is not broker_id column, but last_name and first_name

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are including `b.first_name` and `b.last_name` in your select clause, without either aggregating them or grouping by them.

You can either add both items to the group by clause, or use an aggregation function (such as `max`) on each of them in the select clause, to make your query work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your GROUP BY clause into:
 ...
 GROUP BY b.first_name, b.last_name